# Индекс элемента по которому был клик. Как узнать?

Tags: javascript

Есть кнопки. По клику на каждую происходит вызов поап окна с соответствующим содержанием кнопке.
Как мне узнать по кнопке с каким индексом был клик и например вывести кнопку в консоль после этого?

Спасибо.

Код на данном этапе:

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
    let buttons = document.querySelectorAll('.map-button');
    let coordinates = {
        SaintPetersburg: [59.907185064216456, 30.32360249999998],
        Yekaterinburg: [56.82273506788084, 60.611883499999976],
        RostovOnDon: [47.24534707428573, 39.7049965],
        Samara: [53.223802571189786, 50.19369900000003],
        Novosibirsk: [55.04674406964771, 82.95779049999999],
        Ufa: [54.78367356988649, 56.040994499999876],
        Krasnodar: [45.02704307457372, 39.02962499999993],
        Voronezh: [51.685813572274064, 39.17126249999992],
        Vladivostok: [43.14411057453034, 131.90757449999995],
        Kazan: [55.75232856899768, 49.16086099999994]
    };
    let center;

    buttons.forEach(button => {
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            
        });
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Индекс узнать очень просто:

```
buttons.forEach((button, index) => {
                      // ^^^^^
        button.addEventListener('click', function () {
            
        });
    });
```

Comment: Спасибо большущее, дружище!

Comment: А такой еще вопрос. Я могу обратиться к свойству ключа объекта по индексу?

Comment: Не понял вопроса. `buttons[i].getAttribute('name')`  типа такого?  в целом в текущем случае можно и просто `button.getAttribute('name')`

Comment: Не. Мне теперь, зная индекс кнопки, по такому же индексу нужно обратиться к одному из свойств ключа объекта coordinates и записать это свойство в переменную center.

Comment: ну только если циклом пробегаться. также по свойствам и когда i будет равен индексу... то да......но мне кажется можно проще - где-то в кнопке должно храниться имя ключа, при клике его доставать и в объекте уже обращаться по этому имени

Comment: Попробую с циклом.

Comment: С кнопкой и именем ключа было бы проще конечно, но я внедряю код в сайт на cms..........костыли

Comment: Спасибо за помощь!